# How to set events in HTML built from string?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used a [Bootstrap dialog box](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) to get a file input, where the user first selects the type and then selects the file - I want to limit the files by extension with regard to the type selected.

Bootstrap dialog is built by a string and I was thinking of adding an `onchange` event to the selector as in the following, which I hoped would update the extension in `accept` in file input  - but it gives an error `setType is not defined`.

How can I correctly dynamically capture the selected type and set it in the `accept` in the input where the HTML is built from string?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/0c3d0885/)

```
var HTMLmessage = 'Type: <select onchange="setType(this)"> ..Option list </select> <br> <input type="file" accept=' + getType() + '>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `jQuery` for this. and use `on(change)` event of `jQuery`.
Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0c3d0885/4/).

Piece of code

```
$(document).on("change", '#load-file-type', function(event) { 
  getType = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-ext');
  $('#load-file').attr('accept',getType); // simply using this you can set it in the `accept` in file input.
});
```

Which allow you to trigger event on change.

Comment: When you select a file and then change the option again- then the extension is not filtered. Why is it?

Comment: I tried and extension is filtering for me. not sure weather i checked wrong thing. You want to clear selected file after extension change?

Answer (score 1):

you need event delegation https://jsfiddle.net/0c3d0885/1/ . As you are modifing/adding element after DOMload

```
 document.getElementById('load-file-type').onchange = function setType(op) {
   console.log(op);
   getType = op.dataset.dataExt;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use event bubbling to be able to capture elements that are created at runtime. Similar to jQuerys event delegation.

Here is what you could do.

```js
var optionList = [{
  name: "XML",
  id: "xmlVAL",
  extension: ".xml"
}, {
  name: "JSON",
  id: "jsonVAL",
  extension: ".json"
}, {
  name: "CSV",
  id: "csvVAL",
  extension: ".csv"
}];
var typeOptions = (function(arr) {
  var str = "";
  arr.map(function(type) {
    var op = "<option value=" + type.id + " data-ext=" + type.extension + " >" + type.name + "</option>";
    str += op;
  });
  return str;
})(optionList);

var getType = ".xml";

function setType(op) {
  // console.log(op);
  getType = op.dataset.dataExt;
}
var message = ' Type: <select id="load-file-type" >' + typeOptions + ' </select> <br>  File: <input id="load-file" type="file" style="display:inline" accept=' + getType + ' >'

document.getElementById("result").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "select") {
    return;
  };
  console.log(target.options[target.selectedIndex].dataset.ext);
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
```

```html
<div id="result">

</div>
```